# Automatic js: true on rspec system specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

all my system tests/specs have `js: true`, is there a way to automatically add that tag/metadata to my system tests/specs?

```rb
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "redirect_to", js: true do
  ...
end
```

**Edit**: Hmmm, I was relying on `js: true` for database_cleaner but replaced it with `type: :system` and now I don't need this hack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
config.before(:each, type: :system) { |example| example.metadata[:js] = true }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the default driver to be selenium, or selenium_chrome, or any other custom driver: https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#selecting-the-driver

Something like:

```rb
# spec/rails_helper.rb

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
```

Comment: I already do that: `driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless`